subtract dates and get the result in number of months
I have a dataframe df with a field "d" which represents a date. I would like to create a "nb month" field whose values ​​are (d of the next line) - (d of the current line). I would like the number of months as a result.
import pandas as pd
data = {'id': [1, 2, 3], 'd': ['2020-01-01', '2021-06-15', '2022-12-28']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['d'] = pd.to_datetime(df['d'])
df['nb month'] = df['d'].shift(-1).dt.to_period('M') - df['d'].dt.to_period('M')


I think you can use diff() to substract dates
df['nb month'] = df['d'].diff().dt.days // 30

@BugHunter That would fail for dates "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01".

@e-motta You are right this will handle dates precisely
df['nb month'] = df['d'].diff().apply(lambda x: x / pd.Timedelta(days=1) * 12 / 365.25).fillna(0).round(0).astype(int) 

You can just modify your answer to use the n accessor:
df['nb month'] = (df['d'].shift(-1).dt.to_period('M')-df['d'].dt.to_period('M')
                 ).apply(lambda x: x.n if pd.notna(x) else pd.NA)

which is equivalent to:
df['nb month'] = (-df['d'].dt.to_period('M').diff(-1)
                 ).apply(lambda x: x.n if pd.notna(x) else pd.NA)

Or, more efficient, first convert to integer, then use diff and multiply by -1:
df['nb_month'] = -df['d'].dt.to_period('M').astype(int).diff(-1)

# or use the absolute value depending on the desired logic
# df['nb_month'] = df['d'].dt.to_period('M').astype(int).abs()

Output:
   id          d  nb month
0   1 2020-01-01      17.0
1   2 2021-06-15      18.0
2   3 2022-12-28       NaN


You can modify your code slightly to get the number of months as int and use numpy.where to handle the last row.
df["nb_months"] = np.where(
    df["d"].shift(-1).dt.to_period("M").isna(),
    np.nan,
    df["d"].shift(-1).dt.to_period("M").astype(int)
    - df["d"].dt.to_period("M").astype(int),
)

   id          d  nb_months
0   1 2020-01-01       17.0
1   2 2021-06-15       18.0
2   3 2022-12-28        NaN


You can achieve this by creating a new column using df['nb_month'] = (df['d'].shift(-1) - df['d']) // np.timedelta64(1, 'M'). Ensure your dataframe is sorted by date to calculate correctly.

Hello, I tried this code and I get an error: ValueError: Unit M is not supported. Only unambiguous timedelta values durations are supported. Allowed units are 'W', 'D', 'h', 'm', 's',
'ms', 'us', 'ns'. When i use 'm' i get value like this -786240.0.

'm' stands for minutes.
